# Why won't my applet run on computers without JDK?

Tags: java, netbeans, japplet

I am starting to learn Java. The actual language is not a problem since I am very experienced with C++, but obviously deployment is very different. I used Netbeans 7.1.1 and created a JApplet and used the "web start" option to generate a small test webpage. It runs perfectly well on my computer, but on any computer without JDK installed it doesn't work at all. In fact, it redirects to the *JRE* download page on chrome. Is there a trick? I don't really know what I'm doing here.

I might need to post more information, but I honestly wouldn't know what that is, so please add a comment if I need to post more info.

EDIT: It **really** requires the JDK for some reason. Of course I wouldn't try to run it on a PC without the JRE. Try it on a PC without the JDK http://dl.dropbox.com/u/416909/wossname/wossname.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to run your java applications, the target computer must have JRE (Java Runtime Environment) installed. Java applications run on JRE, they are not standalone like C++ executables.

The point that confused you is that; when you installed JDK on yur development computer, JRE was silently installed with it too.

Can not test right now, but can you try with a different HTML code using < applet> tags like the following;

```
<applet id="testVM" alt="Java is not working." codebase=".."   code="WossnameCalc" archive="Kol-Wossname.jar" width="1000" wight="942">
<param name="locale" value="en" /> 
</applet>
```

the problem might be the "deployJava.runApplet" function in your generated code.

Comment: This is wrong, it needs the JDK for some reason! I don't know why but please don't assume I am just confused.

Comment: OK, just to be clear; does it just forward to JRE download page despite you already installed and running JRE? Are there other error messages?

Comment: "OK, just to be clear; does it just forward to JRE download page despite you already installed and running JRE?"

Yes

"Are there other error messages?"

Not that I know of. It only does the forwarding in Chrome. On IE it just doesn't load.

Comment: I edited my answer for a probable solution. Can you check it?

Comment: What do you mean by "web start"?  That applet is not deployed using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 2):

The browser needs the Java runtime (the JRE) to run your applet.  Are you sure it needs the JDK (the Java Development Kit), or does it need the JRE?  To run, you should need the JRE, not the JDK.

Comment: I posted above, it needs the JDK for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

The device needs a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) to run Java applications (including applets) on it. That is why it is redirecting to JRE download page where the device doesn't have a JRE installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JRE if you need to run any Java programs. Java applications are platform-independent applications. In order to run on any machines, a virtual machine is required. Hence, a JRE (since it converts the Java bytecode to native machine code) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted the most likely explanation - that it needs a JRE - and rlbond responded that the target computer has JRE.

I still think that the JRE explanation is correct.  I am speculating that the browser on the target computer is not set up correctly.  It does not know about the installed JRE.  Since the browser does not know about the JRE, things are the same as if they were not an installed JRE.

So a question for rlbond is "Does the target computer run any other applets?"

Comment: Also, it's more than one PC which has problems. As soon as I install JDK it runs perfectly. I thought maybe it needed Java 7 (which is not available in JRE format) but in the compilation settings it's set to JDK 6.